# Open Port on External Network with VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, ping

I have a Windows 7 laptop that connects to a network with a VPN.

As soon as the laptop connects to the VPN, it becomes unreachable by its physical IP address.
The instant it disconnects, it becomes reachable again.

In other words, if I ping the laptop forever (by IP address) from a different machine in its physical network, it will reply.
The instant I connect the laptop to the VPN, it stops replying.
The instant I disconnect the laptop from the VPN, it starts replying again.

This is not a name resolution issue.

Why is this happening?
Is there a workaround?

**EDIT**: I believe that Windows 7's Virtual WiFi (which the laptop supports) might help here, but I haven't found any documentation.

Comment: Does anyone have a better title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is quite complicated. Your machine is still on the physical network, but a good VPN client does several things including Encryption/IPSec and Firewall.

It all comes down to policy and settings on the client, but most of them route all network traffic over the vpn link (Bridging your network and the remote one) and act as a firewall blocking everything locally.

Comment: Is there a workaround? I own and run the server.

Comment: If you can't configure it, use a different VPN program that supports it - there isn't really a good answer, sorry.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7's built-in VPN client.